# Rails get associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, belongs-to

I have a model with two associations to the same model:

```
class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'UserFrom', :foreign_key => 'user_from'
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'UserTo', :foreign_key => 'user_to'
end
```

When I run the following code in the index action it does not get the correct associated models, any suggestions?

```
@mails = Mail.where('user_to = ?', current_user.id)
```

When using `debug` on each row the data it only shows this:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Mail
  attributes:
    id: 1
    created_at: 2013-02-13 21:17:41.962000000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-02-13 21:17:41.962000000 Z
    user_to: 1
    user_from: 2
    subject: Testing
    body: Mail body blah blah blahhh
    read:
    read_at:
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:class_name` option tells Rails well... the class name. Here (I'm assuming) you don't have a class called UserFrom or UserTo. You have one class called User in app/models.

```
class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_from, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_from'
  belongs_to :user_to,   :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_to'
end
```

I am going to assume the foreign key is setup properly, and that both of them contain user IDs, even though they don't have an `_id` suffix.

As for `@mails`, your query should work. But it would be easier if you declared a `has_many :mails` association on your user. This would allow you to do something like `current_user.mails`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have relations named the same. You have to rename your relations, this is an example:

```
class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_from'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_to'
end
```

I also recommand you to rename the foreign keys, like "sender_id" and "receiver_id" for more readability.

Usage:

```
@mails = Mail.where(sender: current_user)
```

Comment: Just went into the DB and changed the foreign keys and appended _id to each of them. In the controller I have used the where clause you supplied, however it comes with an error: 'SQL error or missing database (no such column: mails.sender)'....

I'd hazard a guess and say this is due to me not properly creating the relationships, are there any additional actions i need to do in order to crete a relationship?

Comment: You will have to change your Mails migration to use `t.references :sender` so that it will create a `sender_id` column in this case. Make sure to also update your `:foreign_key` options on the Mail model to reflect that change as well.

Comment: I've managed to migrate two references and use '@mails = Mail.where(receiver_id: current_user)' to get the mails, however I still cannot get the associated user for each mail. What am I missing?